# Validation tests in Ruby on Rails always false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, testing, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am writing some unit tests in Ruby on Rails. Even when I expect the test to have an outcome that passes the validation, the test fails. 
Here is my model that I am testing:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    def permitted_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :category_id, :admin_user_id)
    end
    belongs_to :category
    belongs_to :admin_user
    has_many :comment, :dependent => :destroy
    validates :title, presence: false
    validates_length_of :body, :minimum => 0
end
```

Here are my tests for this model:

```
class PostTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # test "the truth" do
  #    assert true
  # end
  test "If title is there" do
    post = Post.create(:title => "", :body => "")
    assert post.valid?
  end

  test "If body is long enough" do
    post = Post.create(:title => "Some Title", :body => "hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh")
    assert post.valid?
  end
end
```

This is the error message:

```
F

Failure:
PostTest#test_If_title_is_there [test/models/post_test.rb:9]:
Expected false to be truthy.
```

I get two failures after running my test. I am using Ruby on Rails version 5.2.1 and Ruby version 2.5.1. Any help would be much appreciated. I am not quite sure why both tests are failing. Thank you in advance.

Comment: call `Post.create!` to assert validity. Then the error spew contains the reason your post is invalid. It might not be what you think.

Comment: `validates :title, presence: false`, so is a post without a title supposed to be valid?

Comment: What is this point of this : `validates :title, presence: false` ? Why is there a title attribute if you don't want it to be present?

Answer (score 2):

There is no point in having `validates :title, presence: false`

Most probably you want to validate the presence of title, so you should have `presence: true`.

In addition, I don't see any sense for validating length, against zero.

Also, I'd edit your code in the following way, since there is no point in having strong_parameters in the model.

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :category
    belongs_to :admin_user

    has_many :comment, dependent: :destroy
    validates :title, presence: false
    validates :body, length: { minimum: 0 }
end
```

And finally, you can use https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers for more convenient validations testing.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question on why both tests are failing, the reason I believe is with `validates :title, presence: false` like others have pointed out and I don't think it's needed here.

1) I believe the first one fails because you are setting the title to an empty string. I could be wrong, but try setting it to `nil` and see if it still fails.

2) Similar to the first test, you are setting a title while your code expects it to not be present, causing the validation to also fail.

Hope this helped clearing some things up for you.